# Minimizing window issue in Qt 5.15

Tags: qt, qml, window-resize, minimized, frameless

```
Window {
    id: mainWindow

    width: 960
    height: 600

    flags:  Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.Window

    Rectangle {
        width: 15
        height: 15

        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            
            topMargin: 10
            leftMargin: 910
        }

        SvgImage {
            width: 11
            height: 2

            source: "images/Collapse.svg"

            anchors {
                centerIn: parent
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouse
    
            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }
            
            onPressed: {
                mainWindow.showMinimized()
            }
        }
     
        Timer {
            repeat: true
            interval: 1000
            running: true

            onTriggered: {
                console.log("mouse.pressed = ", mouse.pressed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I faced an issue with Qt.FramelessWindowHint. After using showMinimized() function I restore the window but then any click on window causes minimizing window again. mouseArea never gets pressed. I tried putting Timer printing mouse.pressed valueand it's false all the time.
I found the several links on this issue but there's no solution except going to fullscreen when restoring window. My application always stays the same size and never goes to fullscreen.

https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33298-Qt-FramelessWindowHint-qgraphicsview-qgraphicwidget-showminimized-problem

https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/42641-QML-rendering-problems-after-showMinimized()

[QML: rendering problems after showMinimized()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416993/qml-rendering-problems-after-showminimized)

Maybe you could give me a hint for workaround. Btw I'm using Qt 5.15

Comment: what is `SvgImage`? I think your Bug was because of that. remove it and try my example too. you can add an `SVG` image in `Image { }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onClicked` insted of `onPressed` inside the `MouseArea`.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I could not see any windows after running your code
I add `visible: true` and I removed `SvgImage`.

**This is what I run:**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow

    width: 960
    height: 600
    visible: true

    flags:  Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.Window


    Rectangle {
        width: 15
        height: 15
        color: "#f50909"

        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left

            topMargin: 10
            leftMargin: 910
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: mouse

            anchors {
                fill: parent
            }

            onPressed: {
                mainWindow.showMinimized()
            }
        }


    }


}
```

**This is my result and it works correctly:**

[image]

Comment: Removing SvgImage and clicking on rectangle item gives the same result.Steps to reproduce the bug: click on theitem so to minimize the window, Click on application item on the task bar in order to show it again, click in any place of the window (not rectangle item) - the result - it's minimized again and it's wrong

Comment: @Valeriia what are your `Qt Version` and `Os` and `compiler`? because I try it and it works OK for me. My Os is ubuntu 20.04 and I use Qt 6.2.3, `GCC` compiler.

Comment: Maybe your window `focus` was changed or maybe that relates to your qt version or maybe this happens on windows. I don't know if you use windows or not but I had a similar problem in past with windows.

Comment: I use Windows 10 and Qt 5.15 with Qmake compiler

Comment: @Valeriia  I suggest you test qt in ubuntu in VMWare,I am sure this code is logically correct and works correctly.

Comment: I think so too but I need to run it successfully on Windows, that's why I asked for any kind of workaround